# Convert GPX/KMZ to google maps directions

Tags: google-maps, gps, gpx, kmz

Is there a way to convert a set of waypoints in a GPX/KMZ file to driving directions suitable for Google Maps.
There are numerous sites listing community generated routes which I am unable to load onto my TomTom Start GPS device so I'm looking for an alternative. The logical alternative seems to download Google Maps content for offline usage and convert the set of waypoints to a route format compatible with Google Maps

Alternatively, any other apps able to turn a set of waypoints into driving directions will also suffice as an answer.

Comment: Great question, I generated a trail up a mt peak in the White Mountains in New Hampshire, and I intended to do what you are trying to. I know there a few apps you can download. I was able to upload the GPX points to some of the apps I found but I was never able to have it track me on or off line. Check out this one http://www.gpxnavigator.com/

Comment: The idea was to download a section of google maps for offline use and load my KMZ as a halfway solution. Unfortunately, Google Maps will suffer sudden attacks of amnesia, realise it's no longer online and dispose of the waypoints layer until it reconnects and is able to download the waypoints layer again.

Comment: so check out the link above. The app works, you can upload waypoints and the GPS tracks you on the road. this ESRI tool will convert and feature to GPX points to upload to the app or any other app that takes GPX points http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=067d6ab392b24497b8466eb8447ea7eb